# AKKA: Communicating via Messaging Queue

Tags: scala, groovy, akka, zeromq

We have a component written in Groovy ( let's call it a "G-Component" ) that needs to communicate with a component written in Scala / AKKA ( let's call it an "A-Component" ).

What fits our needs best is a messaging queue:

```
"G-COMPONENT" <==> in memory messaging queue <==> "A-COMPONENT"
```

For the "G-COMPONENT" life is simple:

```
queue.send( message )
message = queue.receive()
```

For the AKKA component it seems a bit more involved, since there is an Actor that needs to "handle"/"receive" messages, and be able to "send" messages back.

The problem is the "receive" part, as it now needs to go into a loop of its own to listen for messages from the queue. Which.. disables it as an AKKA Actor, since once it is in that loop, it can't receive any AKKA messages.

Would appreciate any help on the clean solution for this, without implementing an AKKA plugin of "that particular queue implementation" Actor mailbox.

Comment: I don't understand, are you using a queue as a bidirectional channel??

Comment: Is it AMQP, JMS, 0MQ, java.util.Queue or what is it?

Comment: Viktor, yes, "G-COMPONENT" and "A-COMPONENT" can both send and receive to/from the queue. It is ØMQ, as no broker here is needed + it is the fastest.

Comment: Yup, then using the 0Mq module in Akka is the way to go.

Comment: That was my feeling as well, have not yet tried it hence thank you for confirming. Two questions from here: 1. Do you want to convert this comment to an answer? 2. Since it is integrated on top of JNA, I would not expect a stellar performance ( it is not even over JNI ) => is that a reasonable expectation?

Comment: Well, you didn't say if The different components were inproc or not. if they are in-proc and there's a 1-1 relation between messages sent and replies received, you could simply have the G-component send messages to the actor using ?/ask

Comment: Components are decoupled and run as different processes / JVMs => not "in proc".

Comment: Alright, then co with the 0MQ module :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### *converting a "question edit" to an answer*

Found an interesting development going of not yet officially released AKKA API:

"*Akka provides a [ZeroMQ module](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.3-RC5/scala/zeromq.html) which abstracts a ZeroMQ connection and therefore allows interaction between Akka actors to take place over ZeroMQ connections.*"

Seems that I can have an AKKA way to spawn a ZeroMQ listener:

```
val listener = actorOf(new Actor {
  def receive: Receive = {
    case message: ZMQMessage => ...
    case _ => ...
  }
}).start

val socket = ZMQ.newSocket(SocketParameters(context, SocketType.Sub, Some(listener)))
socket ! Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:1234")
socket ! Subscribe(Seq())
```

*confirmed by Viktor Klang (question comments) this is the way to go*

Comment: how could this be refactored to enable a pool of actors to increase the throughput of a reply socket?

Answer (score 1):

This may be obvious but Akka has excellent camel and amqp integration.

http://akka.io/docs/akka-modules/1.2/modules/camel.html
http://akka.io/docs/akka-modules/1.2/modules/amqp.html

I am not sure what you mean by 'without implementing an AKKA plugin of "that particular queue implementation" Actor mailbox'. Does that mean you don't want to use these components?

Comment: Andrew, one of the solutions is to write a ØMQ (in my case) mailbox and set it as a main (durable) mailbox for my Actors => which I don't want to do. Would bringing another player, such as Camel be the only solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

AKKA is a library not a programming language.

Just write the zeromq message listener outside of an actor, and have it send incoming zeromq messages to AKKA actors. I've done this with AMQP using the Java AMQP client library and it works just fine.

If you want the ZeroMQ listener to be running in an event loop, then it is easy enough to write your own using the select poller [http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-poll](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-poll) Have a look at the ConcurrentSocketActor source code in the AKKA zeromq module because that's what it uses. This would be a good model if you ever need to roll your own concurrent actor for some other type of network communication.

And this is the same problem that people have when they want to add a network accessible management interface to a non-network application in any language.

Comment: right, and that is how we have it implemented currently. The problem is communicating with/to that listener in a "messaging passing" fashion from other Actors. e.g. "Suspend It", "Stop It", "Get a Message Received Count", etc.. Hence it would be great if that "listener" is also a real AKKA "actor", and instead of just messages from the ØMQ queue, it could receive and react to "case object"/"case class" messages. Which is exactly what a [ZeroMQ module](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.3-RC5/scala/zeromq.html) allows.